# Save image, loaded on https to http directory with action from http

Tags: php, jquery, http, post, https

I have loaded image on site with HTTPS. Form on HTTPS is as follows:

```
<form id="imageuploader" action="http://url/actionImageUpload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="uploadframe">   
    <iframe id="uploadframe" name="uploadframe" src="" width="8" height="8" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="display: none;"></iframe>

    <img src="http://url/images/<?=$this->id?>.jpg"/>

    <input type="file" name="ac_image" id="ac_image"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="cat_id" value="<?=$this->id?>"/>
</form>
```

Action on HTTP http://url/actionImageUpload saves image from income $_FILES to http://url/images/ directory with file name cat_id.jpg(cat_id - hidden value on form).
Also idea is to catch success uploading with JQuery and target of iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $jQ(document).ready(function() {
        $jQ("#ac_image").change(function() {
            $jQ("#uploadframe").load( function() {
                console.log('iframe loaded');
                $jQ("#uploadframe").unbind('load');
                $jQ("#loading").remove();
                $jQ("#full_shadow").remove();
                $jQ("#imageuploader img").attr('src', $jQ("#imageuploader img").attr('src') +'?'+ new Date().getTime());
                $jQ("#imageuploader img").removeClass('no-image');
            });

            setTimeout(function() {
                loadingBox();
                $jQ("#imageuploader").submit();
            }, 0);
        });
    });
</script>
```

If both sites are on HTTP it works correct. But if I sent request from HTTPS to HTTP got error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://url/currentPageWithForm' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure form action 'http://url/actionImageUpload'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Can anybody help how resolve it?

Comment: You mix `http` and `https`. That's the error you get. You need to change the `http` requests to `https`

Comment: ^ or make the `action` on the `form` a relative path, so that it always uses the same protocol as the parent page. Same for the images. You should avoid absolute URLs in HTML where possible.